# How to change position of donut chart slices

Tags: r, ggpubr

I am trying to produce a donut chart. Below is my code. I want the slices to appear in the same order they are listed in the code. Is there a way to do this?

```
library(ggpubr)
df <- data.frame(
group = c("Much lower",
        "A little\n lower",
        "The same \n as before",
        "A little \n higher", 
        "Much\n higher"),
value = c(16, 29, 34, 14, 7))
# create labels
df$label <- paste(df$group,paste(df$value,"%"), sep = "\n")

ggpubr::ggdonutchart(df, "value",
                 label = "label", # add labels
                 lab.font = c(.1,"plain",'white'),
                 color = "white",fill = "group",
                 lab.adjust = ,
                 lab.pos = c("out"),
                 palette = c("gray82","gold1","gray36", "ivory","dodgerblue2")) +
theme(legend.position = "none") #DELETES LEGEND
```

Comment: Use `forcats::fct_inorder()` to the `group` variable.

Comment: I'm still not clear on how to integrate this into the code. Where exactly should I add this?

Comment: `df$group <- forcats::fct_inorder(df$group)`